# Conditional Probability for Investing Bitcoin

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Below is a table of 2 random variables, $x=$ # of houses an individual owns. (for example x=0 represents an individual having 0 houses). $y=0$ means not investing into bitcoin and $y=1$ means investing into bitcoin:

[image: Bitcoin]

Calculate the probability that an individual is investing into bitcoin and owns at least 1 house.

The probability I need to calculate is $P(x \geq 1 \cap y=1)$. Since these 2 variables are not independent of each other, I cannot multiply them right away.

Using the formula $P(x \geq 1 \cap y=1)=P(x \geq 1|y=1)P(y=1)$, I need to find these values. $P(y=1)$ is easy, but what about $P(x \geq 1|y=1)$?

Comment: $P(x \geq 1 \cap y=1)$ is easier than $P(x \geq 1 \mid y=1)$, and can be read from the table without any multiplication or division

Comment: @Henry Ah thanks I tunnel visioned and could not see the big picture here.